# Set ROOT_URL of meteor app on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, meteor

The title pretty much says it all. How do you do it?

I'm trying to set up the accounts-facebook package but it keeps passing localhost off for the OAUTH handshake.

On a *nix environment, it's done as such:

```
ROOT_URL="http://www.mydomain.com/" meteor run
```

but this doesn't work on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant test it for you, but you would set it like any other ENV variable in windows...

http://itechtalk.com/thread3595.html should help

Or [on the command line](http://commandwindows.com/variables.htm):

```
set some_variable = some_value
```

Comment: Sorry bout that! You're right - I forgot to open up a new terminal to pull in the new env variables. Thanks!

Comment: can  you provide the exact command you used to run the meteor app using ROOT_URL in windows ?

Comment: I haven't worked with meteor in about 8 months, Sorry, I cannot help.

Comment: Exact command:
`set ROOT_URL=http://www.example.com:3000`  (I tried doublequotes but meteor didn't like it)

Answer (score 0):

Easy two line version:

```
set ROOT_URL=http://www.example.com:3000
meteor run
```

One line version, if you really need it:

```
cmd /c "set ROOT_URL=http://www.example.com:3000&& meteor run"
```

(Notice there is no space between the URL and the &&: the space gets included in the URL, which breaks meteor, as it will use that space in its URL.)

*Source:* [Setting environment variable for just one command in Windows cmd.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/223104/setting-environment-variable-for-just-one-command-in-windows-cmd-exe)